# Error while importing tables in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

i am trying to import table individually using UI. I am directly importing table without creating it prior.
It gives me error message to Create the table before import.
but import option should create table structure according to file columns.
How to import without creating tables prior using PostgreSQL?

Comment: Which UI are you using

Comment: from pgAdminIII, when i right click and select option of import/Export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case ,TABLE according to the import file must be created first. IF there is no prior table , it wont work.
This may help.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/